# How to redirect user and admin to a different template after login in Django 2

Tags: django-templates, django-views, django-2.0

I'm new in Django 2. I try to develop a project where my requirement is from the same login page **user** and **admin** can log in but when user login he will view his own **dashboard** and admin will view his own different **dashboard**.

My views.py code is

```
def loginCheck(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        admin = authenticate(request, is_staff=1, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        elif admin is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('admin')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Wrong User Name Or Password')
            return redirect('loginView')
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'You Have To Login First')
    return redirect('loginView')
```

I Was trying to get `is_staff` value to *authenticate* admin and user but not getting success. Now how can I login from the same login form and give the user and admin a different dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In above code you are authenticating a single user twice that's a bad practice. for your requirement we can do like below.

```
def loginCheck(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user and user.is_staff is False:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        elif user and user.is_staff is True:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('admin')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Wrong User Name Or Password')
            return redirect('loginView')
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'You Have To Login First')
    return redirect('loginView')
```